# Microscopic definition/expression of/for the heat current

Tags: statistical-mechanics, solid-state-physics

Often I see the following microscopic definition/expression of/for a heat current due to an external field
$$
{\bf j}_Q = 2 \int \frac{\text{d}{\bf k}}{(2\pi)^3} \frac{\hbar {\bf k}}{m} (\epsilon_{{\bf k}} -\mu) f(\epsilon_{{\bf k}}),
$$
where $f$ is the solution the the appropriate Boltzmann equation. Note that the factor of two is there for the spin of electrons. I do not really understand where this expression comes from. Especially the factor $(\epsilon_{{\bf k}} -\mu) $ bothers me. Does it tell us that only electrons near the Fermi level contribute to the heat current? Or does it have another meaning?

Comment: Could you give some sources and context where this formula appears?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us decompose the formula to better understand what it means:

- $\hbar \mathbf k/m$ is the velocity of the electrons
- $\epsilon_k - \mu$ is the energy relative to the temperature, so if particles with higher energy than the temperature move in a direction, they produce a positive thermal energy flux, particles with lower energy an negative flux.
- $f(\epsilon_k)$ tells who many particles are in this state.
  That only electrons near the Fermi level contribute has nothing to do with $(\epsilon_k - \mu)$. This states that particles with energy near the chemical potential $\mu$ contribute only little, as this term is small.

The fact that (at least for temperatures $k_BT \ll E_F$) the electrons near the Fermi energy contribute to this flux, is due to the fact that those are the most mobile one. Higher energy levels are mostly empty, therefore not contributing, and lower energy levels are completely full, therefore the integral vanishes, and they don't contribute ether.

Comment: +1 @user3384414 All I would add is that f(e_k) is most likely the Fermi function.
(I'm guessing it's the heat flow from electrons.)
To the OP: The distinction between different distributions is important. You might want to look up how Boltzmann, Fermi, and Bose-Einstein distributions differ.

Comment: @GeorgeHerold $f(\epsilon_k)$ is definitely not the Fermi function, as this would yield zero (you need an odd function in $k$ for it to survive the integral).

Comment: @user3384414 Thanks for the answer. The only thing which is still not clear to me is point two. How do you interpret this term as the energy relative to the energy?